# Is this nodejs code a circular reference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, closures

They are just a few lines from node.js official documents.

```
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
  client.end();
});
```

I think client object has reference to the callback, the callback has a closure reference to client object. Is that correct? If yes, why is this encouraged?

Comment: `client` within the callback references the original client due to the scope, so it cannot be referencing any other `client` unless you redefine it. This doesn't cause any scoping issues, so it's safe to use. The only other way would be to pass in client as an argument (you don't have control over what the framework passes) or define client in another scope like `window`, which could introduce more problems and has no improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a circular reference, but it is not a memory leak. Given just this code snippet, you only have a small graph of a handful of objects, but yes, as long as `client` is reachable from your main program, all of these objects will never be eligible for garbage collection. However, if you were to set `client = null;`, The graph of objects including the `client` object and the anonymous event handler function would be unreachable from the main program and thus eligible for garbage collection and thus A-OK.

This pattern in and of itself is not a memory leak. If you were to create clients in a loop and keep a reference to all of them in an array or object with no code to ever dispose of stale clients, then yes, that would be a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you. There may be more complicated circular references. Can I say that two objects that reference each other, whether direct or indirect, they will be garbage-collected by V8? Only when one of these are referenced by a third object, there will be memory leak?

Comment: That's correct. If an entire large graph of objects becomes unreachable from the runnable portion of the code, that entire graph is eligible for garbage collection. Most typical code patterns such as above will not cause leaks. Be vigilant when using objects or arrays as caches, maps, collections, etc as those are likely candidates for add-but-never-remove error leaks.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. Event Emitters in node.js store their listeners in a private _listeners property.
your handler function uses `client` as a closured variable, which is not strictly necessary because all handlers are called with the event emitter as the `this` reference.

However, using `this` instead of `client` doesn't change the fact that `client` is in the closure, it just hints V8 to dereference it from the closure because it is not used.

Even if it was used from the closure, V8 has sufficient logic to handles this kind of circular references and free them from memory properly.

Comment: Thank you. So we should not worry about circular references in this pattern?